# Transmitting data from Android to Nao Robot

Tags: ros, nao-robot, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am now developing a system which consists of Nao robot and a VR headset with an Android phone. What I am trying to do now is getting yaw and pitch values using accelerometer of Android phone and transmitting those values to Nao robot so that when I move my head to right, Nao will do the same.

For this purpose, I have to somehow send data from Android phone to Nao robot. The first thing that came into my mind is developing a simple web app in PC and send data to Nao when a new data arrived.

My question is that is there any better way to send data from Android to Nao Robot? Notice that, latency is an important factor for me.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259718/transmitting-data-from-android-to-nao-robot/) by [mehmet](https://answers.ros.org/users/29539/mehmet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@mehmet take a look at http://wiki.ros.org/android and http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava.

Rosjava will allow you to run nodes in Android using Java. You should be able to write a node that takes the information from the IMU and publishes it to ROS.

Regarding the IMU, I'd take a look around here: https://github.com/ernestmc/android_roloc.

A bit late, but hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0